# After writing the file, part of the original file remains in the file

Tags: c#, file

After writing the file, part of the original file remains in the file

I use C# to write modules to save software settings, but I found that if the original settings file is longer, the end of the new settings file after overwriting will always have the tail of the previous settings information.

Below is my changed code:

```
    public void SaveToFile(string pathName)
     {
         try
         {
             using (var sw =new StreamWriter(
                 File. Open(
                     pathName,
                     FileMode. OpenOrCreate
             )))
             {
                 sw. Write(this. ToString());
                 XXXSystem.Log(this.ToString());
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             XXXSystem.Log("An error occurred while saving the configuration file: " + ex.ToString());
         }

     }
```

Comment: Just delete the file before you write.

Comment: This isn't a question about using Visual Studio, so I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Oshawott gave an even cleaner alternative:

```
new StreamWriter(pathName, false)
```

**Original answer:**

Change

```
File.Open(pathName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
```

To

```
File.Open(pathName, FileMode.Create)
```

The descriptions of the different file modes are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-7.0). You can also use intellisense in your IDE to see them easily.

Also - if you’re using an IDE, please use the code formatting features..

Comment: Or just `new StreamWriter(pathName, false)` to set overwriting mode with [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)).

Comment: @Oshawott good one! I’ve amended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) class wraps a lot of common file actions, including the ability to [`WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0) to a file.

The `WriteAllText` method will create a new file (or overwrite an existing file) with the contents of the string you pass to it:

```
public void SaveToFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the file, or overwrite if the file exists.
        File.WriteAllText(path, this.ToString());
        XXXSystem.Log(this.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XXXSystem.Log(
            $"An error occurred while saving the configuration file: {ex}";
    }
}
```